# Monitor Magento site for availability

Tags: php, magento-1.6

I have a magento site on a VPS. This VPS runs plesk and backs up to an external FTP server.

I have an intermittent problem in that if the FTP server is unavailable, the backup is stored instead on the VPS itself. This is fine if there is sufficient storage available. If not, the backup simply consumes all the available space, and any visitors to my Magento site get the default magento maintenance / error page('There has been an error processing your request').

I like the idea of using phpQuery on a remote server to monitor and alert me (via email probably the best way) if the site slips into unavailability, but wondered if anyone has some predefined scripts I can plagiarise.?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about server monitoring and not Magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't recommend any scripts but have a look at [Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com/).  Amongst other things you can set this to send an email alert when your site goes down, and I believe you can also have it look for certain content on the site so it will alert if the site is actually up but is displaying an error message for instance.

You may also want to look at [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) which is a free tool you can use to monitor the general health of the server including things like disk space and inode usage and take some action once a predefined threshold is exceeded i.e. delete an old local backup.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at these. Pingdom looks handy, but I was hoping to implement something with little or no cost. Also, not sure how it will handle the fact that apache is still running, just not serving magento pages... might use the free trial option to give it a blast.

Comment: Have a test of Pingdom, but as I noted in my answer I believe you can tell it to look for page content to determine the up status of the site, i.e. a title you would expect to see on the homepage, and if it's not there (because an error message is showing etc.) an alert will be sent.  I haven't used the service myself but a number of my clients do and they seem to get on pretty well with it.

Comment: If you want service monitoring and management, check out Monit, it's what we use.

Comment: Yeah, already looked at Monit. It will be  handy for monitoring server status, but doesn't really fit with Magento monitoring as it will only report if a service goes down - i.e. apache itself. In my case above, apache is still running.